# Data recovery from a RAID1 disk

Tags: raid-1, data-recovery

I extracted the disk from a Mybook World 2 (White Led).
The device has only this 1TB SATA disk, and it seems it is using RAID1

This is a report from disktype:

```
francesco@blackhole:~$ sudo disktype /dev/sdb
--- /dev/sdb
Block device, size 931.5 GiB (1000204886016 bytes)
DOS/MBR partition map
Partition 1: 1.869 GiB (2006974464 bytes, 3919872 sectors from 64320)
  Type 0xFD (Linux raid autodetect)
  Ext3 file system
    UUID 78C28AA5-BDFD-4BE6-9F58-90158E3B0E34 (DCE, v4)
    Volume size 1.869 GiB (2006908928 bytes, 489968 blocks of 4 KiB)
  Linux RAID disk, version 0.90.0
    RAID1 set using 2 regular -1 spare disks
    RAID set UUID 03D291C1-5D91-F02A-42F0-E4F5C3F82B1D (NCS)
Partition 2: 251.0 MiB (263159808 bytes, 513984 sectors from 3984192)
  Type 0xFD (Linux raid autodetect)
  Linux RAID disk, version 0.90.0
    RAID1 set using 2 regular -1 spare disks
    RAID set UUID A1A39027-5114-9598-6F0E-78C3AC55D2B2 (NCS)
  Linux swap, version 2, subversion 1, 4 KiB pages, little-endian
    Swap size 250.9 MiB (263053312 bytes, 64222 pages of 4 KiB)
Partition 3: 964.8 MiB (1011712000 bytes, 1976000 sectors from 4498176)
  Type 0xFD (Linux raid autodetect)
  Ext3 file system
    UUID 0AEEE999-BE23-4CC1-A5B8-71EBE9DF871E (DCE, v4)
    Volume size 964.8 MiB (1011613696 bytes, 246976 blocks of 4 KiB)
  Linux RAID disk, version 0.90.0
    RAID1 set using 2 regular -1 spare disks
    RAID set UUID 71CAFCD8-5E07-B57B-1C59-C590CF05141F (NCS)
Partition 4: 928.4 GiB (996887495168 bytes, 1947045889 sectors from 6474176)
  Type 0xFD (Linux raid autodetect)
  Linux RAID disk, version 0.90.0
    RAID1 set using 2 regular -1 spare disks
    RAID set UUID 8B3DEF8B-534C-90D1-D7BA-B2FE15673C8F (MS GUID)
  XFS file system, version 4
    Volume name ""
    UUID 100D6A32-784A-4250-9B41-8E193B998415 (DCE, v4)
    Volume size 928.4 GiB (996887363584 bytes, 243380704 blocks of 4 KiB)
```

The important files are in sdb4.

I tried to mount it:

```
sudo mount -t xfs -o ro /dev/sdb4 /media/recovery/
```

But it fails saying that the filesystem is wrong, or the superblock damaged.

I also tried mdadm:

```
sudo mdadm --assemble /dev/md4 /dev/sdb4
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/sdb4
mdadm: /dev/sdb4 has no superblock - assembly aborted
```

Any idea to access the XFS filesystem?

Comment: "The device has only this 1TB SATA disk, and it seems it is using RAID1" If it only has one drive, it's not using RAID1. Just restore from backup.

Comment: How can I recover it if I cannot mount it? And why disktype reported "Linux raid autodetect" as partition type?

Comment: Unless he was mirroring to partitions. Which is totally insane if you know how RAID works, but it would not be the first time I encountered this.

Comment: Hennes: no, it is not mirroring two partitions.

Comment: Not my downvote. Though something is really wrong here. Read this link first http://serverfault.com/questions/339128/what-are-the-different-widely-used-raid-levels-and-when-should-i-consider-them  After reading it you should understand why a 1 disk RAID makes no sense.

Comment: Just to be clear: I *did not* create this RAID setup. It has been created by Western Digital. I just need to mount this partition.

Comment: According to the manual ( http://www.wdc.com/wdproducts/library/UM/ENG/4779-705013.pdf ) that NAS is able to handle two drives. Could it be that it previously used two drives and someone already removed one? Or that the setup was done in RAID in anticipation of a second drive and just started in degraded mode?

Comment: There is a 2TB version of that NAS, but mine has only one disk. Probably the 2TB version uses 2x1TB disks in RAID. And probably WD configured even 1-disk NAS in RAID, even if it is pointless.
Do you how can I mount this disk? :-(

Comment: @Francesco - you recover from a **backup**.

Comment: @ErikA: If I had a backup, why would I asked how to recover from the disk itself?

Comment: People on ServerFault are assumed to have off-site backups. (But this question probably should have been asked on superuser). As for how to recover the data: I I knew a surefire way I would have posted that as an answerAs it is a am guessing and asking more question to get an idea of what is going on and how things are set up.  There is an party who knows though, that is the manufacturer.